# Converting ODataModel into JSON Model

Tags: json, odata, sapui5

Because of problems with reading all lines of a UI5 common table and the `getModel()` method from table offers a model.

I thought I could use a JSONModel instead of my ODataModel, the problem now is how to get the ODataModel to the JSONModel.
Because JSON offers some Two Way Binding options which should be helpful.

I tried to read some set and bind it to the JSONModel, the problem is that I couldn't bind the new model two the view because it doesn't offer some set.

Here is a snippet of my code. Hopefully this should be easier too fix as the reading all table rows:

```
//Erstellung des Modells
var oModel2 = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url, true, username, password);
var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("QuickStartApplication.model", "/Search.json"));

oModel2.setSizeLimit(8000000);
var pspJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var oODataJSONModelDLSet = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var oODataJSONModelProjectSet = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var oODataJSONModelPSPset = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
var debitorJSONModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
this.getView().setModel(pspJSONModel, "jsonmodel2");
this.getView().setModel(oODataJSONModelDLSet, "jsonmodel");
this.getView().setModel(oODataJSONModelProjectSet, "jsonmodel3");
this.getView().setModel(oODataJSONModelPSPset, "jsonmodel4");
this.getView().setModel(debitorJSONModel, "jsonmodel5");
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "saves");
// etc

oModel2.read("/SEARCH_DLSet", null, null, false, function (oData, oResponse) {
    oODataJSONModelDLSet.setData({ DLSet: oData });
});
oModel2.read("/Search_ProjectsSet", null, null, false, function (oData, oResponse) {
    oODataJSONModelProjectSet.setData({ ProjectSet: oData });
});
oModel2.read("/SEARCH_PSPSet", null, null, false, function (oData, oResponse) {
    oODataJSONModelPSPset.setData({ PSPset: oData });
});
oModel2.read("/DebitorSet", null, null, false, function (oData, oResponse) {
    debitorJSONModel.setData({ DebitorSet: oData });
});
oModel2.read("/PSPSet", null, null, false, function (oData, oResponse) {
    pspJSONModel.setData({ Pspset2: oData });
});
var json1 = pspJSONModel.getJSON();
var json2 = oODataJSONModelDLSet.getJSON();
```

I saw that the table row binding has found the correct length of the data that it should get but the column binding won't work. Here is a code snippet of row binding and then the column

```
                            <Text text="PSP(A-Nr.)" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" ></Text>
                            <ComboBox id="combo1"  items="{path: 'jsonmodel2>/Pspset2/results'}">
                                <core:Item key="{jsonmodel2>Psp}" text="{jsonmodel2>Psp}" />
                            </ComboBox>         

                            <Text text="Abrechnungsstatus" class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" ></Text>
                            <ComboBox id="Abrechnungsstatus"></ComboBox>                    
                        </l:VerticalLayout>
                    </l:HorizontalLayout>
                </l:VerticalLayout> 
             </l:HorizontalLayout> 
             </ScrollContainer> 
         </Panel>   
     <Panel visible="false" height="80%" width="98%" id="__layout15" class="__layout5">
<Button text="Edit" id="edit" type="Transparent" class="buttons" press="onEditRow"> </Button>
        <t:Table class="table0" id="table1" selectionMode="MultiToggle" rows="{jsonmodel>/DLSet/results}">
            <t:columns>
                <t:Column class="columns"  width="105px">
                    <Label text="Kontrakt Nr." id="lKontrakt" >
                    </Label>    
                    <t:template>
                        <commons:TextField id="Kontrakt" editable="false" value="{jsonmodel>KontraktNr}" ></commons:TextField>
                    </t:template>                   
                </t:Column>
```

Also my two OData Models got on first binding property the set name under sPath but my new one won't get this property.

Here are some Screens from debugging:

[OModel 1 with first property of binding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tqk7X.png)

[New Model with first property of binding but no right path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHOwT.png)

Update examples of how the json Result looks like:
PSPSet:

```
{
  "Pspset2": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "http://hvw-sapdev01.oms-sap.omnisys.de:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV/PSPSet('00014158001')",
          "uri": "http://hvw-sapdev01.oms-sap.omnisys.de:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV/PSPSet('00014158001')",
          "type": "Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV.PSP"
        },
        "Psp": "00014158001"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "http://hvw-sapdev01.oms-sap.omnisys.de:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV/PSPSet('00030173001')",
          "uri": "http://hvw-sapdev01.oms-sap.omnisys.de:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV/PSPSet('00030173001')",
          "type": "Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV.PSP"
        },
        "Psp": "00030173001"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And DLSet:

```
{
  "DLSet": {
    "results": [
      {
        "__metadata": {
          "id": "http://hvw-sapdev01.oms-sap.omnisys.de:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV/SEARCH_DLSet(9168)",
          "uri": "http://hvw-sapdev01.oms-sap.omnisys.de:8000/sap/opu/odata/SAP/Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV/SEARCH_DLSet(9168)",
          "type": "Z_TBRKNPRO_SEARCH_DL_SRV.SEARCH_DL"
        },
        "Abrechungsstatus": "",
        "Contractnr": "",
        "DatumHigh": "",
        "DatumLow": "",
        "Login": "",
        "Mandant": "",
        "Mitarbeiter": "",
        "Name": "",
        "Psp": "",
        "Client": "001",
        "Id": 9168,
        "Impdate": "",
        "Ldatum": "20130705",
        "Lperiode": "",
        "PersNr": "49056462",
        "PersName": "J",
        "PersGrade": "",
        "LocalGradeKey": "",
        "LocalGradeDesc": "",
        "PersKstN": "",
        "PersKstB": "",
        "AufKstNr": "",
        "AufKstBe": "",
        "AufNr": "",
        "AufBez": "",
        "Bemerkung": "",
        "DebitorId": "0000037503",
        "DebitorBez": "G",
        "ProdCodeNr": "T130",
        "ProdCodeBez": "Allg. Steuerberatung von Unternehmen",
        "IndustCodeNr": "99999",
        "IndustCodeBez": "H",
        "ArbZ": "5.0000000000000000E-01",
        "ScaleRate": "280.0000",
        "MarketRate": "280.0000",
        "ScaleValue": "0.0000",
        "CostRate": "0.0000",
        "CukyCostRt": "",
        "Fakturiert": "",
        "FakeLdate": "",
        "Confidential": "",
        "KontraktNr": "5000059735",
        "PrctrHead": "",
        "Honorar": "140.0000",
        "Kosten": "140.0000",
        "SatzNeu": "280.0000",
        "HonorarNeu": "140.0000"
      },
      {
        "__metadata": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC-BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted and subsequent attempts will get you banned. If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395/584192)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code seems really unclear, here's a pointer on how you could implement it:

You read the OData response into a JSONModel:

```
var oModel2 = new sap.ui.odata.ODataModel();
var oODataJSONModelDLSet = new sap.ui.json.JSONModel();

this.getView().setModel(oODataJSONModelDLSet, "jsonmodel");

// etc

oModel2.read("/SEARCH_DLSet" + filterString, null, null, false, function (oData, oResponse) {
    oODataJSONModelDLSet.setData({ DLSet: oData });
});
```

...you then bind to your view:

```
<t:Table rows="{jsonmodel>/DLSet/results}">
    <t:columns>
        <t:Column>
            <Label text="Kontrakt Nr." /> 
            <t:template >
                <commons:TextField value="{jsonmodel>KontraktNr}" />
            </t:template>                   
        </t:Column>
```

EDIT: Updated answer based on updated question

Comment: so i tried too get my code a little bit cleare so i need then to read all sets to my JSONModel i think so so i did it like this

Comment: and bindet it like you told me the problem if got to is that only the psp binding is working ok i know why sry thats my fault only one odata for each set

Comment: There will be a degraded performance if your have tens of thousands of records, but other than that, it should just work. `aBindings` should not contain the data, just the binding info I think. The model's data is in the `oData` property

Comment: yeah that the problem the data is in oData but aBindings just don't get the Complete Binding informations but i can't change this manualy so i don't know if this is a Bug or i just doing something wrong I created every thing the same ways and bind it the same way why i get not the same way the bindings.

Comment: Really hard to tell.. I have never ever seen it fail, so there must be something in your code. Can you provide a simplified jsbin or plnkr example?

Comment: I tried but i doesn't get backend connection over plnkr so its not possible to get this working i can take some screens again of debugin and ui and something like that where the problems comes and here on scn: http://scn.sap.com/thread/3882425 are already on last post some new screens

Comment: Can you then at least provide a JSON representation of what your JSON model looks like? The class structure doesn't tell me much. Again, your fields bindings are wrong and without knowing the json structure we're shooting in the dark. Really, this is just basic javascript stuff

Comment: I updated modeldata to DLSet and because of i needed 5 JSONModels with different binding names and i bindet it with DLSet/results allready.

Comment: But it still doesn't and i don't know why because the upper combo box is working i written above my updated code which is working wiht this json data.

Comment: See this working example : http://jsbin.com/lazesuk/edit?html,js,output (I faked your odata response, but it works the same regardless) It just works, so there **must** be something else wrong in your code. Can't help you any further I guess

Comment: I see and i tryed it to implement this in too my file and the json model was created but my table too couldn't load the data is it possible that i should try to use sap.ui.m.table? Because my sap.ui.table.table bugs or just won't work with json?

Comment: No, they both should work just fine. I would advice to step through the debugger, esp. the asynchronous parts where you add the odata response to your json model, and see if anything looks supicious. Also, use the SAPUI5 diagnostics screen to check for any "binding invalid" messages

Comment: Okay i've got it you where right it was another code error in my code i just rebindet it and doesn't see that before dump failure.

Answer (score 0):

First: did you properly attached your JSONModel to your view, using the 'jsonmodel' name (because you refer to it in your table's binding)

Then, have you checked the structure of the oData object ? you are asking something like:

```
{ oData : { results : [... ] } }
```

Finally in the text field you do not reference 'jsonmodel' again, you should put {jsonmodel>KontraktNr} instead of just {KontraktNr}

Comment: yeah i am named the model when i  am binding the model too the table,  
Too second under {oData : { reuslts : { [...][...][...]}} the results of the request are fitted in.  
And yeah I did this before another on in scn told me that i should try it   without but yeah i thought before i did this it couldn't been alright.