# Is there an elegant way to get JSON Data from OdataV4 Model in Openui5?

Tags: json, odata, sapui5

(openui5 Version 1.42)

Hello,

I have a list of items, whose data is provided by an odatav4 model (sap.ui.model.odata.v4.ODataModel)

When I select an Item, I bind it to a detail view with its own controller.

Now I would like to get the data from the odata model.
This solution does not work, as the odata v4 model does not support the read method:
[Converting ODataModel into JSON Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36278900/converting-odatamodel-into-json-model)

Is there a way to get the data of the selected entry as json (model or directly as data)?

What I can get is a property from the context in my controller:

`this.getView().getBindingContext("ams").getProperty("Ident)`

returns `1`. The Identifier of my selected entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Context.getObject](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Context.html#getObject). This delivers the complete object that the context points to. However there is a bug in 1.42; the result is wrapped and you have to access it via `.value[0]`. This bug has been fixed in 1.44.7. See the [release notes](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.44.7/#docs/guide/05ce1dc72c74475bada39234f6721f21.html).

A solution that works in 1.42 and all following releases is to make use of the fact that getObject also can deliver parts of the object. Deliver an empty sPath parameter:

```
this.getView().getBindingContext("ams").getObject("")
```

Comment: what is that "ams" in getBindingContext?

Answer (score 3):

If you call the method [getObject](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.Context.html#getObject) on the binding context you should get the entity as json.

```
this.getView().getBindingContext("ams").getObject()
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. That was the right direction. In addition I had to get the value, though: `this.getView().getBindingContext("ams").getObject().value[0]`